# force child objects to implement static method

Tags: c#, .net

I want to allow all my child objects to implement static method. For example:

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B : A {}
public class C : A {}
```

I want B and C to have DoSomething() static method, where in A there will be default implementation of DoSomething().

What is the bes practice to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do so. You wouldn't be able to *call* the static method polymorphically anyway. Basically, static members and polymorphism don't work together. Either give up on polymorphism, or create a parallel type hierarchy where those are *instance* methods.

Comment: Could you see any merit in theoretically being able to do this?

Comment: @JonAlb: In some cases, yes. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx for an example.